Pytorch meshgrid
I'm currently using torch 1.12 for my thesis on neural A star algorithm and i'm not quite sure what meshgrid does. For example why
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
y = torch.tensor([4, 5, 6])
torch.meshgrid(x, y)

return
tensor([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])
tensor([[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]])

and not
tensor([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])
tensor([[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]])


It all depends on the indexing mode you use: ij or xy (default is ij):
>>> torch.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='xy')
(tensor([[1, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 3]]),
 tensor([[4, 4, 4],
         [5, 5, 5],
         [6, 6, 6]]))

Here is a visualization of the two mesh grids:


If you are not interested in this structure and prefer the expected result, you can use a combination of stack, transpose and repeat:
torch.hstack((x[:,None], y[:,None])).T[...,None].repeat(1,1,3)
tensor([[[1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [3, 3, 3]],

        [[4, 4, 4],
         [5, 5, 5],
         [6, 6, 6]]])


 torch.meshgrid(x, y) is used to create a grid of coordinates based on two 1-dimensional tensors, More Here
x represents the values along the rows and y represents the values along the columns
If you want to see expected just swap x and y
import torch

x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
y = torch.tensor([4, 5, 6])


torch.meshgrid(y, x)

You get#
tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]])
tensor([[4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6]])

More like
  y/x  1   2   3
       ___________
    4 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
       -----------
    5 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
       -----------
    6 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
       -----------

y are rows and x are col. Each cell contains a pair of coordinates (x, y)

import torch 

x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
y = torch.tensor([4, 5, 6])

# Using default 'ij' indexing
res1 = torch.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
print(res1)
'''
(tensor([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]]), 
 
 tensor([[4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6]]))

'''
# Using 'xy' indexing
res2 = torch.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='xy')
print(res2)
'''
(tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]), 
 
 tensor([[4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6]]))

'''

